# How to .map render list of items grouped into category in React

Tags: reactjs

Hello guys i wanted to render some items into their own category using `.map`, but i dont know how to do it . I only know how to render standard list. Below is the example of my data:

```
[
       {
        "id_kategoriTest": 1,
        "kategori": "Hematologi",
        "id_jenisTest": 24,
        "jenis": "Coombs Test Direct"
    },
    {
        "id_kategoriTest": 1,
        "kategori": "Hematologi",
        "id_jenisTest": 25,
        "jenis": "Hb Elektroforesis"
    },
    {
        "id_kategoriTest": 14,
        "kategori": "Imuno-Serologi",
        "id_jenisTest": 247,
        "jenis": "Anti HBs Titer"
    },
    {
        "id_kategoriTest": 14,
        "kategori": "Imuno-Serologi",
        "id_jenisTest": 248,
        "jenis": "Anti HBc"
    }
]
```

The output i wanted is like this:

**Hematologi**

- Coombs Test Direct
- Hb Elektroforesis

**Imuno-Serology**

- Anti HBs Titer
- Anti HBc

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step is to sort your array to something more convenient.
Then render the sorted array.

Here, `myArray` contain your array above

```
  const sorterAR = [];
  myArray.forEach((item) => {
    let cat = sorterAR.find(
      (cat) => cat.id_kategoriTest === item.id_kategoriTest
    );
    if (!cat) {
      cat = {
        id_kategoriTest: item.id_kategoriTest,
        kategori: item.kategori,
        items: [],
      };
      sorterAR.push(cat);
    }
    cat.items.push(item);
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {sorterAR.map((cat) => (
        <>
          <div>
            <b>{cat.kategori}</b>
          </div>
          <ul>
            {cat.items.map((item) => (
              <li>{item.jenis}</li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, appreciate it. Sorry if i didn't provide code what i've been tried. Because my code showing result with duplicated categories loop.